# Running a synchronous call after awaiting an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am writing a node js program as follows. The purpose of this code is to parse from multiple pages of an API (variable number of pages thus scraping the first page to see how many pages are to be scraped) followed by uploading all the pages to MongoDB and then "analysing the pages" with a function in another file (manipulate keyword):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const config = require('./config.json')
const manipulate = require('./manipulateDB')

async function startAHLoop() {
        async function getAuctionPage(page = 0) {
            return fetch(`https://website.net/page/${page}`).then(res => {
                return res.json()
            }).catch (error => console.error("Faced an error: " + error))
        }

    async function getFullAH() {
        try {
            let ah = []
            let completedPages = 0
            let firstPage = await getAuctionPage(0)
            for (let i = 1; i <= firstPage.totalPages; i++) {
                getAuctionPage(i).then((page) => {
                    if (completedPages !== firstPage.totalPages - 1) {
                        completedPages++
                    }
                    if (page.success) {
                        for (auction of page.auctions) {
                            ah.push(auction)
                            if (completedPages == firstPage.totalPages - 1) {
                                completedPages++
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (completedPages == firstPage.totalPages - 1) {
                        completedPages++
                    }
                })
            }
            // Wait for the whole ah to download
            while (completedPages !== firstPage.totalPages)
                await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10))
            return ah
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Failed to update auctions', e)
            return
        }
    }

    async function main() {
        let startTime = Date.now()
        if (!db.isConnected()) await connectToDB()
        let auctionCollection = data.collection('auctions')

        let ah = await getFullAH()
        let timeTaken = Date.now() - startTime
        if (typeof ah.ok == 'undefined') {
            auctionCollection.drop()
            auctionCollection.insertMany(ah)
            console.log(`Auction update complete in ${timeTaken} ms ${Date().toLocaleString()}`)
            console.log("Starting analysis")
            await auctionCollection.insertMany(ah)
            manipulate.printAHInfos()
        } else {
            console.log(`Auction update failed in ${timeTaken} ms ${Date().toLocaleString()}`)
        }
        // This essentially is the delay instead of every 60000 ms
        setTimeout(main, 60000 - timeTaken)
    }

    main() 
}

async function connectToDB(isFirstConnect) {
    console.log('Connecting to db...')
    MongoClient.connect(
        config.mongoSRV,
        { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
        (err, DB) => {
            if (err) return connectToDB()
            db = DB
            skyblock = DB.db('skyblock')
        }
    )

    while (typeof db == 'undefined') {
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10))
    }

    if (!db.isConnected()) {
        console.log('Something weird happened... re-starting db connection')
        return connectToDB()
    }
    console.log('Successful connection to database')
    if (isFirstConnect) startAHLoop()
    return db
}
connectToDB(true)
```

I am looking for a way to wait until `collection.insertMany(ah)` has finished before doing `manipulate.AHdata`

The issue I get is that `manipulate.AHdata` is invoked before `collection.insertMany(ah)` is finished. Resulting as follows when manipulate.AHdata outputs "Invoked":

```
Invoked
Connecting to db...
```

I tried using the following:

```
collection.insertMany(ah)
await collection.insertMany(ah)
manipulate.AHdata
```

But it doesn't work tho...
Any idea of what I could do?

Thanks for the help and have a great day!

Comment: Can we see actual code instead of pseudo-code? Also what "[doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)"?

Comment: @JeremyThille added my code instead of pseudo code.

Comment: OK that's much better, thanks. You still haven't said what doesn't work, but anyway I see several issues with this code. 1. `startAHLoop()` is marked as `async`, which is useless because you are not `await`ing anything in it, you are only defining other functions. That's odd, you probably want to use a Class for that. 2. Inside the `for` loop, you are doing `getAuctionPage(i).then(` instead of `await getAuctionPage(i)`. In consequence, all `fetch` operations are being launched at the same time, and all the `.then()` will be triggered later, which force you to do this `while` hack.

Comment: "*I tried using the following:*" - uh, don't call `collection.insertMany(ah)` twice? Call it once, and `await` the result.

Comment: 3. Also you should `await MongoClient.connect()` instead of this `while` hack a second time.  At least use a callback function... 4. `data.collection('auctions')` but `data` is undefined, no idea what this is. 5. `skyblock = DB.db('skyblock')` No idea what `skyblock` is, you're not using it anywhere. 6. `if (typeof ah.ok == 'undefined')` How can `ah.ok` be defined? `ah` an array...

Comment: @Bergi there are no expected return value from this operation, therefore I cannot use await for this hence why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Scorpio [`insertMany` does return a promise](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#insertMany), which you can and should `await`.

Comment: @JeremyThille skyblock is the name of the collection in MongoDB. Furthermore, undefined is the return value for MongoDB when you upload data. I edited the file to explain more clearly what doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi I will add this and update this thread accordingly. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Following up with all my comments and points, here's what I believe is a better (but obviously untested) version of the code :

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const config = require('./config.json')
const manipulate = require('./manipulateDB')

let auctionCollection

async function getAuctionPage(page = 0) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://website.net/page/${page}`)
        const data = await response.json()
        return data
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Faced an error: " + err)
    }
}

async function getFullAH() {
    try {

        let ah = []
        let firstPage = await getAuctionPage(0)

        for (let i = 1; i <= firstPage.totalPages; i++) {

            const page = await getAuctionPage(i);

            for (let auction of page.auctions) ah.push(auction);
        }

        return ah
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Failed to update auctions', e)
        return
    }
}

async function main() {

    let startTime = Date.now()
    let ah = await getFullAH()
    let timeTaken = Date.now() - startTime

    auctionCollection.drop()
    auctionCollection.insertMany(ah)
    console.log(`Auction update complete in ${timeTaken} ms ${Date().toLocaleString()}`)
    console.log("Starting analysis")
    await auctionCollection.insertMany(ah)
    manipulate.printAHInfos()

    // This essentially is the delay instead of every 60000 ms
    setTimeout(main, 60000 - timeTaken)
}

async function connectToDB() {

    console.log('Connecting to db...')

    let db

    try {
        db = await MongoClient.connect(
            config.mongoSRV,
            { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    } catch (err) {
        return connectToDB()
    }

    auctionCollection = db.collection('auctions');
    console.log('Successful connection to database')
    main() // You don't need hacks and verifications to check if the DB is connected. If there was a problem, it got caught in the catch()
}
connectToDB()
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I really like your input in the getFullAH function as it simplifies it a lot. On the other hand, after some fixing of few issues, manipulate.printAHInfos() is invoked before the database is uploaded to MongoDB. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: `the database is uploaded to MongoDB` doesn't really mean anything, because MongoDB is a database, you can't upload a database to a database. Now I have no idea why this is happening because I don't know what you wrote :) My code seems correct, I'm awaiting `insertMany` so there's no issue here

Comment: what I meant was that `manipulate.printAHInfos()` is invoked first when running the code (even before connecting to MongoDB) and the await doesn't help.

Comment: Well, I doubt this can happen with my code. I checked it and it seems right. Since I don't know what you have changed and what you've made, merging my code with yours, I have no way to know what's going on. Maybe you have kept a few `.then()` that will mess everything up, I don't know.

Comment: I think I got the issue. It is at the very beginning. `const manipulate = require('./manipulateDB')` is loaded before the script is ran. so instead of using a separate file I just used a new class in the same file so that it doesn't run before.